# GIT Mirror sub directory only

Tags: git

I have a multi repo which is the following;

```
packages
  a
    package.json
  b
    package.json
  c
    readme.md
package.json
readme.md
```

I then have a public repo on github in which i want to mirror c into the root of the repo. Any changes in packages/c repo should appear in the mirrored repo.

A and B are both private independent packages but C will contain the build from B along with documentation. Currently packages/a and packages/b and both working correctly but the mirroring approach for packages/c is confusing me.

Whats the best approach for this?

Comment: Why are you storing the build output in a repository?  Build artifacts don't belong in a repository.

Comment: c will build artifacts from b for publish on npm etc